# ubuntu16.04でログインしたら背景以外表示されない

Tags: ubuntu

現在、ubuntu16.04、Geforce gtx1080を取り付けたデスクトップPCを使用しております。

もともと普通に使用できていましたが、以前にubuntu18.04LTSにアップデートを行ったのがきっかけで、動作が不安定になりました。
直近の問題として、ログインしたら、背景のみが表示され、何も操作できない状態になってしまうことです。
CUIモードではログインはできます。
いろいろ調べて、
DISPLAY=:0.0 gnome-terminal
などを試したりしましたがうまくいきません。

どなたかお力をお貸しいただけないでしょうか

追記：
startx を試したところ、エラーは出ませんでしたが、背景だけの画面の中心にxが表示された状態になりました。ほぼ背景だけの画面、といったところでしょうか

追記２:
デスクトップ環境選択にてGNOME環境を使用すればメニューなどを使用可能になりました

Comment: `startx` コマンドを実行してみてください。その結果エラーが出た場合、それを本文に編集して追記してください。

Comment: ログイン画面でデスクトップ環境が選べるかと思いますが何を選択していますか？（GnomeShell？）

Comment: @hinaloe さん　デスクトップ環境はUbuntu(default)を使用しています。
この選択の存在をはじめて知ったため、GNOME環境を使用したら一応メニューなどが利用できる状態になりましたが、Defaultで使用可能にするためにはどうすればよいでしょうか？